# How to publish an NPM package to a project inside a subgroup in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab, I have a project, that I want to publish as an NPM package, inside a group and subgroup, like this:

```
- fpg (Group)
  - api (Subgroup)
    - api-common (Project)
```

According to Gitlab documentation, "*Packages must be scoped in the root namespace of the project*", so the name of the package is `@fpg/api-common`. However, I can't publish it, receiving the following error when I run `npm publish`:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/@fpg%2fapi-common
```

I've checked that the contents of the `.npmrc` file are correct, and also that the `publishConfig` option in `package.json` has the right URL and project ID. In fact, I have another project inside the `fpg` group (not in the subgroup) and I can publish it without any trouble following the same steps. What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: ```echo "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${YOUR_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc```

Comment: Hi! I already have the project id and token in the `.npmrc` file, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It was completely my fault. The parent group `fpg` was previously named `tests`, but when I renamed it I forgot to change also the path from **Settings** --> **Advanced**. After changing this path, everything works as expected.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

This is how looks my `.npmrc` file

```
@something:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${YOUR_TOKEN}
```

You can also check this `gitlab-ci.yml` example:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/npm.gitlab-ci.yml